# I want to save a number, which I'll be getting from choose_pos() function, in the places list which is in function board_full(). How I do that?

Tags: python-3.x, list, func

```
    def choose():
      choose = 'wrong'
      while choose not in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']:
      choose = input('Which place you want to choose from 1 to 9 ')
    
      if choose not in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']:
        print('Sorry, wrong input! Please try again!')
    
      return int(choose)
    pos = choose()
```

I just take random number from 1 to 9(places) and save it as pos.

```
    def board_full():
      places= []
      places.append(pos)

      if len(places) >=9:
         board_full = True
      else:
         board_full = False
      print(places)

      return board_full
```

then I want to check if all the 9 places are occupied. That's why I'm saving them in the list but with this code only one number gets saved. Every time I run choose() function and then board_full function, it replaces number with the new one.

Comment: Please correct your indentation - your `return`s are both outside of their respective function body, which produces a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a working solution for you. Basically you have problem with the scope of variables and the re-trying mechanism. I have written many comments to my code for the better understanding.

**Code:**

```
def choose():
    choose_str = "wrong"  # I have renamed the variable because it was a shadow name of function.
    while choose_str not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
        choose_str = input("Which place you want to choose from 1 to 9 ")

    if choose_str not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
        print("Sorry, wrong input! Please try again!")

    return int(choose_str)


def board_full():
    places.append(pos)

    if len(places) >= 9:
        board_full_bool = (  # I have renamed the variable because it was a shadow name of function.
            True
        )
        print("Board is full!")
    else:
        board_full_bool = False
    print(places)

    return board_full_bool


places = []  # You have to define the "places" list as global because if it's local in function it will be overwritten in every function call.
pos = choose()  # Get the first element to fill the "pos" variable.
while not board_full():  # Get the numbers from user while the return value of "board_full" is not True
    pos = choose()
```

**Test:**

```
>>> python3 ../test.py

Which place you want to choose from 1 to 9 1
[1]
Which place you want to choose from 1 to 9 2
[1, 2]
Which place you want to choose from 1 to 9 3
[1, 2, 3]
Which place you want to choose from 1 to 9 4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
Which place you want to choose from 1 to 9 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Which place you want to choose from 1 to 9 6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Which place you want to choose from 1 to 9 7
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
Which place you want to choose from 1 to 9 8
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
Which place you want to choose from 1 to 9 9
Board is full!
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```